# Spherical Trigonometry Question

Tags: geometry

Given that $\cos(\lambda) = \sin(\delta)\cos(\epsilon)-\cos(\alpha)\cos(\delta)\sin(\epsilon)$

Can you solve for $\delta$?

Comment: Try making use of Pythagorean identity to turn this into a function of $\sin(\delta)$ or $\cos(\delta)$ and solve from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Define $a=\cos(\lambda)$, $b=\cos(\epsilon)$, $c=\cos(\alpha)\sin(\epsilon)$ so your equation write $$a=b \sin(\delta)-c\cos(\delta)$$ which looks quite familiar, isn't ?

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: doesn't look familiar to me, sorry I'm a highscool student... Do you mean $a^2=b^2\sin^2{\delta}+c^2\cos^2{\delta}-bc\sin{2\delta}$ and then making quadratic?

Comment: No, this is the classical trigonometric equation. Do you know how to solve it ? If you want a solution using a quadratic, just post.